# Using PostGIS to query shapefiles

Tags: postgis, shapefile, query

I am very new to PostGIS (started using it this morning).

My goal is to determine if a lat/long point is contained inside a polygon that is described in a shapefile (The shapefile has a single polygon).

My plan for attack is to import the shapefile into PostGIS (this is the tool I have to use) and run a spatial query. These are my steps:

1) Infer the SRID from the shapefile:

`cat CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT/CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT.prj 
PROJCS["Calgary_3TM_WGS_1984_W114",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["World_Geodetic_System_of_1984_GEM_10C",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-114],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]`

and http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3776/

My best guess is that the SRID I should use is 3776.  I have no background in GIS so I am just making a best guess.

2) Convert the shapefile into .sql file:

`shp2pgsql  -g the_geom_3776 -s "3776" -W "latin1"  CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT/CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT.shp > CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT/CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT.sql`

3) import the shapefile in PostGIS.

`psql -d testdb -f CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT/CALGIS_CITYBOUND_LIMIT.sql`

I want to determine if a lat/long point is inside the perimeter of the City of Calgary.  This are the coordinates: `51.0644894,-114.081923`.  Google tells me they are within the city limits so it must be true.

However, the following query returns `false`:

```
SELECT ST_Contains((select the_geom_3776 from calgis_citybound_limit), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.0644894,-114.081923),   3776));
st_contains 
-------------
 f
(1 row)
```

I have a gut feeling that my projection is wrong but I can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: The projection of your point is 4326

Comment: Thanks @iant.  I think what you are suggesting is: `SELECT ST_Contains((select the_geom_3776 from calgis_citybound_limit), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.0644894,-114.081923),   4326));
 st_contains 
-------------
 f
(1 row)
` which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your coordinates are in lat/lon (EPSG:4326) but you need to convert them into the projection that your polygons are stored in, so your query should be something like:

```
SELECT ST_Contains((select the_geom_3776 from calgis_citybound_limit), 
    ST_Transform(
       ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(51.0644894,-114.081923),4326),
    3776));
```

Comment: Thanks @iant.  This did it. I was getting an error: `ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (51.0645 -114.082 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)` but was able to fix it by switching the long/lat coordinates around.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few fixes to the query:

1. Always use lng/lat (X/Y) axis order for PostGIS.
2. As @iant mentioned, use ST_Transform to do the spatial transformation to 3TM.
3. Flatten the query by removing the subquery (i.e. `select (select ...)`). This subquery is unnecessary and can be slower, as it bypasses any spatial index (if it exists).

This should work:

```
SELECT ST_Contains(the_geom_3776,
    ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-114.081923, 51.0644894), 3776), 4326))
FROM calgis_citybound_limit;
```